# Get re leaving employee's from table

Tags: sql-server, datediff

This is my query I gave from month and to month for retrieve re leaving employee within that months

```
select 
ED.EmpName,
ED.EmpNo,
OP.Dateofjoining,
ED.deactivedate,
DATEDIFF(MM,OP.Dateofjoining,ED.deactivedate) as Totalmonth
from EmployeeDetails ED 
inner join Officialprofile OP on ED.EmpNo=OP.EmpNo 

inner join SalaryDetails SD on ED.ExisistingCode=SD.ExisistingCode 
inner join MonthDetails MD on SD.Month=MD.Months 

where ED.Lcode='UNIT I'and SD.Year='2013' and ED.ActivateMode='N'
and MD.Months>='Augus and MD.Months<='December'
```

I got result no of month using datediff with between to months but in asp.net I have one textbox in that textbox if i give 3 means I want first 3 month employee only

Comment: Can you properly specify what actually are you looking for? If possible, provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of `MD.Months>='Augus and MD.Months<='December'` use `DATEPART(mm,D.deactivedate) < = 3`.
Insted of "3", you can pass value of your text box.